# iOS error : library not found for -lGSDK_Overload

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

After pod update i am seeing the following error

> library not found for -lGSDK_Overload

while trying to build the project. I have been using the Google Analytics in my project. Is this related to Google Analytics ? See the header search path in my project

[image]

I have seen the similar questions in SO. But here i have no idea what is GSDK and where the actual issue lies.

Pod update details

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check for the following solutions

1. Have u launched your project through `[project_name].xcworkspace`
2. Check for `libGSDK_Overload_external.a` library file at following path `file-path/[project_name]/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries/` in your root folder of the project and add this file to projects target.
   Rebuild your project.

[image]

3. If problem still exit remove pod file and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks @vje1998 i file libGSDK_Overload_external.a is already shown in xcode project navigator pane. Do i need to add it explicitly on any other place ?

Comment: it shouldn't throw u the error. Clean and run your project

Comment: I have done that several times. Anyway i will try my luck again

Comment: u try 3rd option and then 1st option it will definately solve this

Comment: What do you mean by "add this file to projects target" mentioned in point 2 ?

Comment: i haven't any issue before updating the pod. When i revert the update it works. So 1st option has no significance here.

Comment: its means to add file to project navigator. in your case its already there

Comment: How did you got this working. I tried all the steps and no luck. All I can do is revert the project and it works.

Answer (score 5):

After a few hours of trying the answer provided by @vje1998 and couple of other stuff like deleting derived data, removing cocoapods all together. I finally fixed it. I hope this helps anybody that might have the same issue.

Under `Build Settings>Linking>Other Linker Flags`. I deleted the row with -lGSDK_Overload. It solved the problem google analytics still works and there are no linker errors. After running `pod install` Other Linker Flags stays the same so I'm assuming that it wasn't needed to begin with.

Comment: Your solution worked! In my project, I had somehow hardcoded the values of Other Linker Flags, so when the Google Analytics pod got updated, the linker flags didn't get automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue:
library not found for -lPods

I fixed it by [Rohit Agre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644572/6004931) option 3

`pod deintegrate`
`rm -r [project_name].xcworkspace`
`pod install`